# hot to set a new title to my android appication in "share via" screen?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

I have added my app to the images "share via"  screen

(adding an intent filter in the manifest)

but I see all apps are organized alphabetically.

How can I change the title of my app so it will appear at the beginning?

I have seen dropbox changed theirs to "add to dropbox"

I want to change only the title for this specific perpuse. Not to change my app name for any use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android:label` on the `ACTION_SEND`  `<intent-filter>`. Since this is static, you cannot guarantee that you will be first, but you can use "Add to" the way Dropbox did.

Comment: @EladBenda: Yes, the manifest is where your `<intent-filter>` element is.